# Definition of substitution in Lambda expression

Tags: types, lambda, theory, lambda-calculus

Let's denote `[x |-> v] t` as "substitute all free occurrences of x in t with v".

The substitution rules of my textbook are

```
[x |-> v] x=v
[x |-> v] y=y (where y is not x)

[x |-> v] (function x -> t) = (function x -> t)
[x |-> v] (function y -> t) (where y is not x) =
        (function y -> [x |-> v]t)

[x |-> v] (t1 t2) ->  ([x |-> v]t1   [x |-> v]t2)
```

I don't quite comprehend the first two rules. **Why whether y is x makes a difference?** Are the first x and the second x in `[x |-> v] x` same? Can y of the second rule be something like `1+x`? **Can you give two examples in Lambda expression or C/C++/C#/Java, that use the two rules, respectively?**

thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule is mapping `x` to `v`.  The second rule is saying any variables that are non-`x` remain unchanged.  Both of those are parts of the the same rule that are necessary to fully define its behavior.

I suppose a somewhat reasonable example would be the following:

```
int x = 1337;
int y = 9001;
int v;
v = x;
```

Note that `v` has now been set to the value of `x` (first rule), but the value of `y` has not changed (second rule).

Comment: In your example, x,y are all variables. Can y be expression that contains x?

Comment: @LoveRight No, for this definition to make sense `x` and `y` must only be variables. If `y` could stand for arbitrary terms, the definition would be wrong. Hopefully your book points out somewhere that it will use `t1`, `t2` etc. to stand for arbitrary terms, `x`, `y` etc. to stand for variables and `v` (and presumably `v1`, `v2` etc if multiple are needed) for values (i.e. irreducible terms) - maybe there's a notations or conventions section where this is written.